# get data from mqtt broker -6lbr

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, beagleboneblack, contiki

I followed this tutorial :

[Running the CC26xx Contiki Examples](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cc26xx_sw_examples)

but instead of using the cc26xx-demo I used the cc26xx-web-demo and successfully manged to get everything up and running and I can access the 6lbr web page, when I access the sensorTag page I see a mqtt configuration page as shown:
[image: sensorTag page]

and if I click index in the sensorTag page (pic above) I get to see the **data**:

[image]

the question is , how can I write a simple nodejs js file that uses the mqtt broker information to grab all the sensorTag ***sensors*** data and save it in an local object.

I tried to do run this example but no luck

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt') 
client = mqtt.createClient(1883, '192.168.1.109'); 
client.subscribe(what do I write here); 
client.on('message', function(topic, message) { console.log(message); });
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

## **UPDATE:**

mqtt configuration page :[image]

javascript file :
[image]

and I run the js with node and listen on port 1883:
[image]

tcpdump seems to detect mqqt packets on 1883 port but I can't to seem to be able to console.log the sensor data when I run the js file with node ??

I went on the contiki wiki and came across this info
"You can also subscribe to topics and receive commands, but this will only work if you use "Org ID" != 'quickstart'. Thus, if you provide a different Org ID (do not forget the auth token!), the device will subscribe to:

iot-2/cmd/+/fmt/json"

does this mean that the topic to subscribe to is quickstart but even if that's so, I used '+/#'  which subrcibes to all topics and still got nothing printing on the console ?

Comment: There are plenty of NodeJS MQTT examples out there, what have you already tried?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late replay: I tried  to do a  simple example

var mqtt = require('mqtt')
 
client = mqtt.createClient(port, host);
 
client.subscribe(what do I write here);
 
client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
  console.log(message);
});

but I'm a but confused as what to subscribe to

Comment: Update the question with what you tried and why it doesn't work

Comment: will do that :D

Comment: updated the question, tried with the code I posted above, still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = { port: PORT, host: HOST };/*user, password and others authentication if there.*/
var client = mqtt.connect('HOST', options);
client.on('connect', function ()
{
    client.subscribe("topic, command or data");

    client.publish("topic, command or data", data, function () {
    });
});

client.on('error', function () { });
client.on('offline', function () { });
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log(message.toString());
});
```

Comment: you mean like this ? :


    var mqtt = require('mqtt');
    var fs = require('fs');

 
    var PORT = 1883;
    var HOST = '0064:ff9b:0000:0000:0000:0000:b8ac:7cbd';
 
    var options = {
    port: PORT,
    host: HOST,
    };
 
    var client = mqtt.connect(options);
 
    client.on('connect', function() {
    client.subscribe('messages');
    });

    client.on('error', function() {
    });

   client.on('offline', function() {
   });

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work , tcp detect mqtt packets but no data is being printed to the console unfortunately :(

Comment: I mean this, Thanks :-)

Comment: I've added 
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
console.log(message)
    });

and no sensor data is being printed to the console even though tcpdump is detecting traffic on port 1883

I also tried console.log(message.toString())
with no luck as well :(

Comment: Can you try this. And in each function write `console.log()` put one after this code `var client = mqtt.connect(options);` as well. Thanks :-)

Comment: it does not print the sensor data to console as well :( 
but tcp dump is picking up traffic

Comment: will try it   now

Comment: I did this 
client.on('connect', function ()

{
        console.log("it arrived at 1")
    client.subscribe("topic, command or data");
        console.log("subbed")


    client.publish("topic, command or data", data, function () {
        console.log("published")
    });

});



client.on('error', function () {console.log("error") });

client.on('offline', function () { console.log("off-line")});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {

    console.log(message.toString());
});
          
and the result when I ran it, it said :
connected
off-line

Comment: In your case problem is in HOST, PORT or something else reference link of above mention code - https://blog.risingstack.com/getting-started-with-nodejs-and-mqtt/